# Why do I get the same error values when training SVMs in R?

Tags: r, data-science, svm, kaggle

I'm trying to model the dataset from the [Framingham Heart study](https://www.kaggle.com/amanajmera1/framingham-heart-study-dataset). This data has some categorical variables and has the following structure (`TenYearCHD` is the dependent variable):

```
'data.frame':   2928 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ male           : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ age            : int  39 48 61 46 43 63 52 43 50 43 ...
 $ education      : int  4 1 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ currentSmoker  : int  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ cigsPerDay     : int  0 20 30 23 0 0 0 30 0 0 ...
 $ BPMeds         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ prevalentStroke: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ prevalentHyp   : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ diabetes       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ totChol        : int  195 245 225 285 228 205 260 225 254 247 ...
 $ sysBP          : num  106 128 150 130 180 ...
 $ diaBP          : num  70 80 95 84 110 71 89 107 76 88 ...
 $ BMI            : num  27 25.3 28.6 23.1 30.3 ...
 $ heartRate      : int  80 75 65 85 77 60 76 93 75 72 ...
 $ glucose        : int  77 70 103 85 99 85 79 88 76 61 ...
 $ TenYearCHD     : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

When I train an SVM using `tune.svm()`, all of the models give the same error (misclassification) rate, regardless of the cost value.

I've tried scaling the data manually and by letting `scale = TRUE` in `tune.svm()`. I've also tried one-hot-encoding the categorical variables. Nothing I've come across and tried has made any difference. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

My code for tuning the model:

```
library(e1071)

dat.train = as.data.frame(scale(dat))

svm1.tune = tune.svm(
  as.factor(TenYearCHD) ~ .,
  data = dat.train,
  type = "C-classification",
  kernel = "linear",
  scale = FALSE,
  cost = seq(from = 0.1, to = 5, by = 0.5),
  cross = 10
)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: You are training the data with the full data set (scaled). Divide it in train/test.

Comment: I have done that. I left it out though 'cause I didn't think it would make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to a combination of a very unbalanced dataset and using the wrong kernel. Once I balanced the dataset with some oversampling, the errors were different for the different cost functions. It looked even better when I then used a radial kernel instead of a linear one.